# Java creating runnable .jar

Tags: java, swing, export, executable-jar

I am trying to export my GUI project as runnable jar file from eclipse. I have selected the main class and created the run configuration. For some reason, when i am trying to start the program by double clicking on it, i got the following error message from JVM Launcher:

**" Could not find the main class, the program will exit "**

```
public class Main {


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setSize(300,300);
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fr.setVisible(true);
}}
```

I created this simple test for the issue, i got the same message. `Main` is in a source folder "src" in default package. At Run Configurations, i simply selected the project, and i selected this class as main class.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running jar with `java -jar <path-to-jar-file>.jar`

If above is working fine then your jar creation do not have any problem and it has created a correct runnable jar. Problem might be with your installation of JDK/JRE.

Comment: It is running from cmd.

Comment: Then it is a runnable jar. Your JDK installation has some issue. You may want to re-install it. The same jar will run on different machine with just double click. You can check it by running on different machine by just double click.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your program is using the same JDK/JRE as the one in your system class-path before exporting your jar file.

You might also check your manifest.txt file by comparing the file in the runnable jar with the one in your project (file should end with a new line).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both java are of same version .

1. On which runnable jar is exported (say java version 1.m.n.z).
2. On Environment where you are running jars(java version should be strictle 1.m.n.z). where target machine having java version

   ```
     Try java -jar <path  where ever your jar is >jarName.jar
   ```

Comment: Did you mean, as an example, when I create a jar with version 5.0.7, I cannot run it on java version 6.0.9?

Comment: You always have backward compatibility provided. There is no requirement that you should have the exact same version. It is only that if you create a jar with higher version, you cannot run it on lower version.